# Identify one row or column of inverse of a matrix (sparse or full)

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let $\textbf{A}$ be a large (sparse) matrix ($size > 10^6\times 10^6$). How to compute $j^{th}$ row or column of $\textbf{A}^{-1}$ at low computational time.

PS: I need to compute only one row of $\textbf{A}^{-1}$.

Comment: How low should the computational time be? Depending on the number of non zero?

Comment: I am looking for 1sec or lower for matrix with size  $10^6 \times 10^6$. I am working with MATLAB. If any parallel algorithm exists, it will be more helpful.

Comment: I meant more like linear, quadratic, ... in $n$ or nnz where the matrix is $n\times n$. Does the matrix has band structure?

Comment: I am happy with any order of convergence at the moment. The matrix is a lower Hessenberg matrix.

Comment: Hm I would still go for an iterative solver. It has basically the same complexity as matrix vector multiplication. Just test it out. It depends on the structure and Hessenberg form isn't much.

Comment: Could you please suggest an iterative solver method for the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43780/discussion-between-midhun-kathanaruparambil-and-user251257).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $j$th column of $A^{-1}$ is the vector $v$ that solves the equation $Av = e_j$, where $e_j$ is the standard basis vector with a $1$ in the $j$th entry and $0$s elsewhere. (Indeed, multiplying by a matrix on the right is like multiplying by many non-interacting column vectors side by side.) Therefore you can apply any known algorithm for solving $Av=e_j$ for $v$.

As for rows, just take transposes of everything first and do the same thing.